# Get centroid of scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, scatter-plot, pca, centroid

I have generated this scatter plot via the plotting of the first two PCA elements from a feature extraction...PCA1 and PCA2.

[image]

The plot shown above is for 3 classes and with PCA1 (x-axis) vs PCA2 (y-axis).  I have generated the plot as follow:

```
target_names = ['class_1', 'class_2', 'class_3']
plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8))
Xt = pca.fit_transform(X)
plot = plt.scatter(Xt[:,0], Xt[:,1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.jet,
            s=30, linewidths=0, alpha=0.7)
#centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
#plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], c=['black', 'green', 'red'], marker='^', s=100, #alpha=0.5);
plt.legend(handles=plot.legend_elements()[0], labels=list(target_names))
plt.show()
```

I wanted to know how to correctly get the centroid of each of the classes from the plot.

Here are the first few columns of the data:

```
Xt1 Xt2 y
-107.988187 -23.70121   1
-128.578852 -20.222378  1
-124.522967 -25.298283  1
-96.222918  -25.028239  1
-95.152954  -23.94496   1
-113.275804 -26.563129  1
-101.803    -24.22359   1
-94.662469  -22.94211   1
-104.118882 -24.037226  1
439.765098  -101.532469 2
50.100362   -34.278841  2
-69.229603  62.178599   2
-60.915475  53.296491   2
64.797364   91.991527   2
-112.815192 0.263505    0
-91.287067  -25.207217  0
-74.181941  -2.457892   0
-83.273718  -0.608004   0
-100.881393 -22.387571  0
-107.861711 -15.848869  0
-85.866992  -18.79126   0
-53.96314   -28.885316  0
-59.195432  -3.373361   0
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `y` an array of labels corresponding to the rows of `X` (and `Xt`)? If so, what are the values of `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `y` is an array of labels corresponding to the rows of `X` (and therefore `Xt`), we can create a data frame with `Xt[:, :2]` and `y` and then use `groupby('y')` to aggregate the mean values for `Xt[:, 0]` and `Xt[:, 1]` for each value of `y`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(Xt[:, :2], columns=['Xt1', 'Xt2'])
df['y'] = y
df.groupby('y').mean()
```

This will produce the means of `Xt[:, 0]` and `Xt[:, 1]` for each label in `y`, which are the centroid coordinates of each label in `y` in the first two principal components of the data.

With the snippet of data that the OP provided, the following script computes the centroids and overlays them on the plot as 'X's of the same color as the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Xt[:, :2], columns=['Xt1', 'Xt2'])
df['y'] = y
df_centroid = df.groupby('y').mean().reset_index()

target_names = ['class_1', 'class_2', 'class_3']
plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8))
plot = plt.scatter(Xt[:, 0], Xt[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.jet,
                   s=30, linewidths=0, alpha=0.5)
# Overlays the centroids on the plot as 'X'
plt.scatter(df_centroid.Xt1, df_centroid.Xt2, marker='x', s=60,
            c=df_centroid.y, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.legend(handles=plot.legend_elements()[0], labels=list(target_names))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response!  How to go about plotting the mean (centroid) on the scatter plot? You are correct on your assumptions of `y` being the labels of each `X` data row.

Comment: @Joe : you should be able to add another scatter plot to the plot before showing it with the data from the resulting data frame: `df_centroid = df.groupby('y').mean()` accessing the centroid as `df_centroid.Xt1` and `df_centroid.Xt2` and the corresponding classes as `df_centroid.y` (to specify the color or symbol to plot the centroid). If you can provide some data (say the first 10 rows of your `Xt` and `y` arrays, I can update my answer to show this.

Comment: Hello, I have just added some data as per your request.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Joe : I have updated my answer to add the centroids to the plot.